# HaxeUI library not working with Lime/openFL/Haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl, lime-haxe, haxeui

I'm trying to run the [HelloWorld sample](http://haxeui.org/hello_world.jsp) provided by [HaxeUI](http://haxeui.org/) in my linux machine.

when I test using Lime or OpenFL like 
`lime test neko`
it gives the following error:

```
/usr/lib/haxe/std/neko/_std/sys/FileSystem.hx:59: characters 21-90 : Error stat
/usr/lib/haxe/std/neko/_std/sys/ssl/Key.hx
/usr/lib/haxe/std/neko/_std/sys/FileSystem.hx:68: characters 9-19 : Called from
/home/ahmadz/openfl/haxeui/1,8,20/haxe/ui/toolkit/core/Macros.hx:225: characters 10-44 : Called from
/home/ahmadz/openfl/haxeui/1,8,20/haxe/ui/toolkit/core/Macros.hx:57: characters 2-18 : Called from
/home/ahmadz/openfl/haxeui/1,8,20/haxe/ui/toolkit/core/Toolkit.hx:50: characters 2-26 : Called from
Aborted
```

however, when I try to test using sudo like `sudo lime test neko`, this error shows up:

```
Called from openfl/_legacy/utils/ByteArray.hx line 760 
Called from openfl/_legacy/Lib.hx line 284 
Called from openfl/_legacy/Lib.hx line 427 Called from openfl/_legacy/Lib.hx line 219 
Called from /usr/lib/haxe/std/neko/Lib.hx line 30 Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library : lime-legacy.ndll (lime-legacy.ndll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Here is my `haxelib list` result:

```
actuate: [1.8.7]
box2d: [1.2.3]
haxeui: [1.8.20]
hscript: [2.0.7]
hxcpp: [3.3.49]
layout: [1.2.1]
lime-samples: [2.6.0]
lime: 2.9.1 [3.0.3]
openfl-samples: [4.0.0]
openfl: 4.0.3 [3.6.1]
swf: [2.2.3]
```

Am I doing something wrong?, I'm an OpenFL beginner and I need HaxeUI for a project I'm working on.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future record and anyone facing the same problem.
I had to switch to Lime 2.9.1 using `haxelib set lime 2.9.1` and now it works!